# Extension of a function in the Sobolev space $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

This question is in reference to the earlier question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903653/extension-operator-for-lipschitz-domain-in-sobolev-spaces).

Let $u(x)=\log\log \frac{2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}}$ where $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\Omega=B(0;2)$. It is easy to see that $u$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$.

How do I extend $u$ to $\mathbb{R}^2\,$? I have seen many standardized texts, but I don't seem to find anything relevant to this.

Does anyone know about any source for this or an extension operator that would work here?

Answer (score 2):

For your very special function $u$ defined in a very special domain $B(0,2)$, one can extend $u$ to $Eu \in H^1(\mathbb R^2)$ by

$$ Eu (x) = \log\log \phi(|x|),$$

where $\phi: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R^+$ is smooth, so that $\phi(y) = \frac{2}{y}$ for $y\le 2$ and $\phi(y) = 0$ for $y>2+\delta$ for some $\delta >0$.

In general the extension operator is defined for all Lipschitz domain, see Theorem 7.25 in [Gilbarg-Trudinger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540411604).